# how to loop function through multiple data frames

Tags: r, loops, square-root, sqrt

i have 30 data frames called moonx.cvs. i would like to loop this square root command and create a new column in each dataframe called 'B' containing the square root value.

```
moon1.csv$B <-sqrt(moon1.csv$Ay^2+moon1.csv$Ax^2+moon1.csv$Az^2)
moon2.csv$B <-sqrt(moon2.csv$Ay^2+moon2.csv$Ax^2+moon2.csv$Az^2)
```

how do i do this across all 30 data frames?

many thanks

Comment: Having a bunch of variable lying around with an index in their name is a big red flag that you are aren't doing things in an R-like way. Life becomes much easier in R if you keep related data in (named) lists so you can easily apply transformations over the collection. Not sure how you wound up with those in the first place, but if you're using `get/assign` I strongly suggest you consider alternatives.

Comment: how do i then retrieve the new column from the list? i would like to do this next: ```lst1 <- lapply(mget(nm1), transform( CA = B-9.81))```    but the new column (B) isn't found?

Comment: But that doesn't update the original data.frames. That creates new version in a list. So you have two copies of the data where one has an extra column. If the data was in a list to begin with, then you could easily replace the original list with the new one.

Comment: apologies - my poor wording  - your latter statement is what i would like to do; create another list, containing the variables in the first list with CA.

Answer (score 3):

We can get the datasets into a  `list` and do all this once and store the output in a `list`.  Assuming that the object names are "moon1.csv", "moon2.csv", ... "moon30.csv"

```
nm1 <- sprintf("moon%d.csv", 1:30)
lst1 <- lapply(mget(nm1), transform, B = sqrt(Ay^2 + Ax^2 + Az^2))
```

---

If we are creating the column names in the original objects in the global env, (not recommended as in each step this may be required again)

```
for(nm in nm1) assign(nm, `[<-`(get(nm), "B", 
         value = with(get(nm), sqrt(Ay^2 + Ax^2 + Az^2))))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst1 <- map(get(nm1), mutate, B = sqrt(Ay^2 + Ax^2 + Az^2))
```

Comment: is there a way of adding B as a new column in each dataframe, without all the dataframes being inside one list?